# How to initiate an outgoing call with message?

Tags: c#, xml, twilio

I'm trying to notify the caller with an automated message. Here is my code below.
string

```
        string AccountSid = "***************";
        string AuthToken = "**************";

        var doc = new XDocument();
        var call = new XElement("call");

        call.Add(new XElement("Say", Message));

        doc.Add(call);


        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        var options = new CallOptions();
        options.Url = doc.ToString(); //Don't have URL need to add XML doc instead
        options.To = Phone;
        options.From = "********";
        var callnow = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You cannot add the XML into the `CallOptions` as shown in the code above. You do need to find a way to place your TwiML into an XML document on a URI accessible by Twilio.

If the message is not dynamic to the call, you could host a static XML file containing TwiML on a service such as Amazon's S3. I have occasionally used Dropbox Public URLs, but only for testing at low volume. But there are lots of options available, including the [TwiMLBin](http://twimlbin.com) service. But if your message is dynamic in any way, you are going to need an application that can respond to HTTP requests.

Is there some particular constraint you have, maybe I can suggest a work around?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any idea why we can't just put xml into the CallOptions?  Seems that this would be the easiest way. I have a C# MVC app, can you show me a sample to output the XML using the Twilio .NET library?  I don't see this in any of the code samples on the Twilio website.

Comment: So, this is a fair question. But when thinking about how Twilio works, the phone calls are quite transactional, you'd usually have an IVR, or some component that requires more than 1 block of XML, and you want that to be dynamic depending on the user. So it makes sense to use a URL. If you really don't need this, and don't want a server, we have a set of Twimlets that can help. The Echo Twimlet will just echo the XML you encode into the URL: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo